# Xamarin forms - Country by Location

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the country of the user using the location. Is there a library or API that can help me with this? And if not, where do you think I can start?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is called "Reverse Geocoding" and can be done using [Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?tabs=ios#using-reverse-geocoding)

```
var lat = 47.673988;
var lon = -122.121513;

var placemarks = await Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(lat, lon);

var placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();
if (placemark != null)
{
    var geocodeAddress =
        $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
        $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
        $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
        $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
        $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
        $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
        $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
        $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
        $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
        $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

    Console.WriteLine(geocodeAddress);
}
```